# Pass Username and Password from JSF or JSP to Oracle Reports

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jstl, oraclereports

I would like to know is there any way using JSF, JSTL or JSP to pass userid and password to another applications without being not visible when user sees the hardcoded value in view source in browser?

Ideally I would want to call Oracle report from either JSF or JSP page, so how can I pass the username and password by not adding in hidden fields or in inputfields, so that when user looks view source in browser he/she should not be able to see the authentication details.

I can add something like

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("username", "SMITH");
map.put("password", "SMT");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap()
        .put("reportParams", map);
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect("http://server:8889/reports/rwservlet");
```

but not sure how can I pass the map with the url or how to call this using JSTL or in JSF page. Even if I pass as parameter, user will be able to see the parameter values perhaps.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read about Single Sign On (SSO) techniques? Your application should never be able to access the password of any user in plain text, so you can't send it to other applications. However SSO gives an approach for not needing to pass it with a centralized authentication point.

Comment: Is the "external" application running in the same web container?

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez We are not using SSO at the moment.

Comment: @w4rumy External applications is in the same application server, however on a different OC4J instance. Thanks

Comment: @Polppan I already guessed that on my own, I'm just suggesting you to do so as it is the most secure way of sharing authentication credentials among different web applications.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez Yes I agree with you, SSO is the best approach for this, at the moment SSO implementation is not possible. And that is the reason I was looking at other solutions. Thanks

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez I have managed to resolve the issue, see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle Report server authentication details can be provided in cgicmd.dat file in the following manner

```
myconn:    userid=scott/tiger@DB report=myreport.jsp %*
```

and use `myconn` while passing parameter from JSF or JSP to Oracle report. In this way hard coding of username or password can be avoided.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for finding a solution that doesn't imply to pass the password in plain text, good find!